# What provisioning profile to give to my developer so he can test app on his iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate

What profile and how do I export it? My developer is asking for a provisioning profile to be able to test the app on his own iPhone. He has asked me to go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> export Apple ID and Code Signing Assets.

If this is correct, that is great. However Im requested to provide a password to be able to export it, and it seems I dont remember it. What do I do then?

Comment: I thought I had the wrong password, but it actually required me to enter it 12 times for each of the profiles..

Comment: can you get his device's uuid

Comment: but the former question stand. Is this the right provisioning profile to give to a third-party developer?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I guess I can... why?

Comment: The password it is asking for is a password that will be used to secure the exported data; you must provide this password to the person who wants to import the profile. You can't "forget it" since you need to create it :)

Comment: @Paulw11: no the password I'm talking about is after the step where you are asked to create one :) it was related to keychain access. it is now solved.

Comment: I did manage to export the profile. However the developer are asked for my AppleId password in addition to the password that I created for him on the profile itself. Seems like I have added a second layer of protection unintentionally. Is there a way to remove the need for my private Apple ID password when using the provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

On way is to get the UUID of his device add it to the development provision profile and archive the project , upload Ipa to [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) , then you will get a link from that site send it to him , he'll open it with safari and install it

Comment: He needs to be able to install new iterations of the app on his phone without my involvement. So I guess your suggestion is better for one of installs....